# Searching for combinations of words and numbers

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails

My model called `Customer` contains a method called `generate_fields` which creates records based on its return values.

```
def generate_fields
  words.map do |word|
    numbers.map do |number|
      content = find_content(word, number)
      next if content.nil?

      {
        kind: word,
        value: content
      }
    end.compact
  end.flatten
end

#[
#  { kind: "S", value: "BRL" },
#  { kind: "M", value: "AUS" },
#  { kind: "L", value: "PER" },
#]
```

The methods `words` and `numbers` are private and return an array of strings. Their implementation is not relevant to this discussion. `generate_fields` returns an array of hashes which is used to create multiple customers at the database.

```
Customer.create(generate_fields)
```

The problem is `compact` and `flatten` create a new array for every time they are called as pointed out by @David Aldridge. How can this function be rewritten to avoid excessive array creation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. As you have currently framed the question, you seem to be asking about a specific practice, with two hypothetical code snippets included merely as an example. To make this question on-topic, please state what task the code accomplishes, and retitle the question accordingly, so that we are reviewing real concrete code from a project. See [ask].

Comment: @200_success thanks for pointing me out in the right direction. I've changed the question and I believe now it's closer to this community guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of the latter because the `compact` and `flatten` methods create new arrays.

Here's another variation with two additional style options: use of `product` to combine the two arrays, and `each_with_object`:

```
def generate_fields_3
  words   = ["foo", "bar", "bla"]
  numbers = [1, 2, 3]

  words.product(numbers).each_with_object([]) do |(word, number), fields|
    content = find_content(word, number)
    next if content.nil?

    fields << {
      kind: word,
      value: content
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I should point out that if efficiency is the aim then the `product` method should be avoided really. For two arrays size N and M it creates another (N*M)+1 arrays.